# Clear all selections in SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="number" name="number">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">04</option>
  <option value="5">05</option>
</select>
<span id="clear">clear all</span>
```

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
  // what should be here?
})
```

How can I clear/remove all selections in `select#number`?

Comment: What do you mean with 'clear/remove all selections'? Do you mean clean the select lists or just disable all option whose have got the 'select' attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('select#number').children().removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

API: http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Hope this help the cause `:)`

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
  $('#number').empty();
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

I update my answer and this should work

```
    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#number option').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("selected");

        });

    });
```

Comment: The `selected` attribute is on the individual `<option>` elements inside the `<select>`, not on the `<select>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("select#number option").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want reset the selection, use

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
   $('select#number').val('');//Cause you have a blank option with value of empty string
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
   $("#number").removeAttr("selected");  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("select#number option").attr("selected", "");
```